# SOAPUI - Is there a setting or plugin to remove empty parent tags in the input XML request?

Tags: soapui

I am doing a data driven testing using SOAPUI (not Pro).  My XML looks similar to the one below:

```
<parent>
    <child1>?</child1>
    <child2>?</child2>
</parent>
<parent>
    <child1>?</child1>
    <child2>?</child2>
</parent>
```

In my datasource (excel sheet), I provide data based on the scenarios.  In some scenarios, data should be given for only 1 set.  The XML in SOAPUI looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <child1>35</child1>
    <child2>45</child2>
</parent>
<parent>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2></child2>
</parent>
```

I have set 'Remove Empty Content' to 'true' in the settings already.  But it looks like SOAPUI is removing the empty child nodes but keeping the parent nodes.  So, the XML that gets posted would look like this:

```
<parent>
    <child1>35</child1>
    <child2>45</child2>
</parent>
<parent>
</parent>
```

Due to this, it errors out.  Is there a setting in SOAPUI or a plugin which can remove empty parent nodes as well?

**Edit:** Can I use XSLT stylesheets for this task?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using groovy for this task?

Check out Scott Davis`s post on creating xml..

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg05199/

Its really easy and super fun.